# How to move files from subdirectories that have the same directory name to its relative upper/parent directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, move

So, I have a directory structure like this:

```
parent/
└── sub1
|    └── sub1.1
|    |    └── source
|    |        └── something1
|    |        └── something2
|    |   
|    └── sub1.2
|         └── source
|             └── something3
|             └── something4
└── sub2
    └── sub2.1
    |    └── source
    |        └── something5
    |        └── something6
    |   
    └── sub2.2
    |     └── source
    |         └── something7
    |         └── something8
    |   
    └── sub2.3
          └── source
              └── something9
              └── something10
```

I want to move all files (with different filename) from all directories named source to its relative upper/parent directory. So, the result should be something like this:

```
parent/
└── sub1
|    └── sub1.1
|    |        └── something1
|    |        └── something2
|    |   
|    └── sub1.2
|             └── something3
|             └── something4
└── sub2
    └── sub2.1
    |        └── something5
    |        └── something6
    |   
    └── sub2.2
    |         └── something7
    |         └── something8
    |   
    └── sub2.3
             └── something9
             └── something10
```

There is a linux example but i am after a batch version.

EDIT: Thanks, that should work. I originally had the below but it will only do one subfolder deep.

```
@echo off
for /D %%I in ("%~dp0*") do (
    if exist "%%I\source\*" (
        move /Y "%%I\source\*" "%%I\" 2>nul
        rd "%%I\source" 2>nul
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small C# program.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Move {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Write("Folder: ");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (var folders in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {
            Console.WriteLine(folders);

            foreach (var subs in Directory.GetDirectories(folders)) {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{subs}");

                foreach (var source in Directory.GetDirectories(subs)) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{source}");

                    foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(source)) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\t{item}");

                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(item);

                        string newPath = $@"{subs}\{filename}";
                        File.Move(item, newPath);
                    }

                        Directory.Delete(source);
                    }
                }

            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```